# Removing linked workbooks external links in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two Excel with the same content but different sizes. If I check with the Excel Add-in called Analyze a workbook with Inquire Add-in (link below) I can see a number of external links that are IMPOSSIBLE to delete. I have tried formatting, symbols, charts, etc, I am still seeing that links in the "analyze a workbook tool". Please, any idea how to delete those links?

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/analyze-a-workbook-with-spreadsheet-inquire-5991e8fa-f1c1-401a-ae3f-469384ae3e3b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Thanks,
P.

Comment: Have you tried the "Edit Links" in the Data tab?

Comment: Yes, I tried everything I know. I checked tons of forums, youtube videos, etc. I still have those links when I check it "Analyze a workbook tool". Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to Copy the relevant cells, and Pasting the Value
(Ctrl + H + V + V) back into the cells. This will keep the value, but remove any links or hidden formatting or formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:
In a new column, enter the formula "=" and click on the cell where you are trying to remove the link (e.g., =A1). I copied and pasted the formula down a whole column, then copied the column, selected "paste special" and "values".  Then I could cut the new column and pasted it over the old column so the text was the same, but the links were gone. Maybe this will work for your links too.